# How to only check empty visible Maskedtextboxes in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have about 50 Maskedtextboxes, only few of them are visible. What I need is to only check the visible ones if they are empty.

I used this code to check all Maskedtextboxes:

```
 Dim empty = TabLABOR.Controls.OfType(Of MaskedTextBox)().Where(Function(txt) txt.Text.Length = 0)
    If empty.Any Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Please fill all fields",
                        String.Join(",", empty.Select(Function(txt) txt.Name))))
    Else
        TabControlBlockD.SelectTab(TabMATERIALS)
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a for each like the following

```
dim myfrm as MyCurrentForm()
```

then

```
for Each item As System.Windows.Forms.Control In myfrm.Controls
        If item.GetType Is GetType(System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTexbox) Then
            For Each mboxes As MaskedTexbox In item.Controls
                If MaskedTexbox.text = "" AND maskedTextbox.visible = true Then
                  //Make deltu king of the world
                 End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

That should work.

edit:

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it. But it's not actually what I want, what I want is to only check the visible ones.

Comment: Oh. put inside the if statement that the condition is that it should be visible. I believe it's done with maskedtextbox.visible = true